# Python get files from FTP based on date of file

Tags: python-2.7, ftp

I need to download files based on their time stamp from the previous day since the naming of the file that contains the date within the filename sometimes bleeds over into another day.

Using python 2.7 on Windows connecting to a FTP server running on IIS.

Here's my code:

```
import os, time
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('example.com')     # connect to host, default port
ftp.login("user", "pass")

ftp.set_pasv('true')
ftp.cwd('TestFolder')               # change into "TestFolder" directory
ftp.retrlines('LIST')           # list directory contents

ftp.quit()
```

It connects and I can retrieve the listing of the folder and it looks like this below:

```
03-13-17  10:00PM                 1337 X1234_20170313220001_1.zip
03-13-17  11:00PM               279579 X1234_20170313230001_1.zip
03-13-17  11:00PM                85477 X1234_20170313230001_2.zip
03-14-17  01:00AM                67923 X1234_20170314010001_1.zip
03-14-17  02:00AM                29524 X1234_20170314020001_1.zip
03-14-17  05:00AM                16022 X1234_20170314050001_1.zip
03-14-17  06:00AM                11272 X1234_20170314060002_1.zip
```

If today is 03-14-17, how do I download all files that have the date stamp of 03-13-17 to a local folder?

Comment: Something like for file in files: if (datetime.datetime.now() - fileTimestamp(file)).days == 1: downloadFile(file)

Comment: I understand your pseudocode, however don't know how to implement using ftplib.

Answer (score 1):

if the FTP server supports MLSD you can try the following.

```
ls = []

ftp.retrlines('MLSD', ls.append)

for entry in ls:
    print entry
```

Then you would just parse the contents, get a datetime object and compare that.

```
modified_date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(entry[(entry.index('=') + 1):entry.index(';')])
```

Otherwise if you can you could use a library to help with this such as ftputil
http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac

Comment: I tried ftp.retrlines('MLSD') earlier, when looking through the documentation, but I got an error so their FTP server may not support MLSD. it's running on IIS, that's all I know for now.